# Unable to take full page screenshot using "screenshot --fullpage"

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am using `Firefox 64.0` on `Windows 10 (1803)`.

In past I have been able to take full page screen captures by issuing the command `screenshot --fullpage` on the browser console. Now using this command gives an error:

```
screenshot --fullpage
SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
```

Should this feature still work in `Firefox 64`? Searching for ways to take full page screen captures leads guides telling to use this command but they all seem to be couple of years old.

If this feature still exists, why is it not working for me? If it does not exist is there a build-in alternative?

Comment: Use colon sign before it.

Comment: Adding colon before command worked but the `--fullpage` parameter still wont work. It gives no error but picture only contains visible area of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prepend a semicolon to the command:

```
:screenshot --fullpage
```

There's more info on that command on [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers#screenshot).

If the `--fullpage` parameter doesn't work, i.e. you only get a screenshot of the viewport instead of the whole page, you either typed it wrong or it's a bug. To check whether it's a general bug in Firefox or caused by some setting or add-on, you should [create a new Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) and try the command there. If it works there, it's related to your profile.
There's also a page giving more [tips how to troubleshoot Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-and-diagnose-firefox-problems).

Comment: It seems that the fullpage parameter only works on some pages.